# Правило написания html-тега

Tags: html

Вопрос звучит странно, я сейчас все объясню.

Вот смотрите вы можете писать теги которые определены стандартом например: `<html>`,`<head>`,`<body>`,`<div>`,`<table>`,`<span>` и т.п.

Но вы можете в принципе писать свои теги не определенные стандартом к примеру: `<screen>`, `<display>`, `<place>` и т.п

Однако мы можем использовать не любые символы в "своих" тегах к примеру:
`<0car>`, `<-car>`, `<машина>` - все это будет обработано браузером так: `"<твой_тег>"<!--твой_тег-->`

Но вернемся к примеру где теги будут корректно приняты, можно также писать `<screen100>` или `<car->` или `<car-моя>` - ошибок нет браузер корректно их отображает в своем DOM дереве.

Я бы хотел найти правила которые разъясняли поведение моих примеров

---

Из ресурсов где я искал это https://html.spec.whatwg.org

Однако тут непонятно почему вторым пунктом полностью не описано каким должен быть первый символ, а какие последущие https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags
Но во втором пункте мы видим ссылку и она нас перекидывает на абзац который гласит:

> Tags contain a tag name, giving the element's name. HTML elements all
>   have names that only use ASCII alphanumerics. In the HTML syntax, tag
>   names, even those for foreign elements, may be written with any mix of
>   lower- and uppercase letters that, when converted to all-lowercase,
>   matches the element's tag name; tag names are case-insensitive.

---

> Теги содержат имя тега, дающее имя элементу. Все элементы HTML
>   имеют имена, которые используют только буквенно-цифровые символы
>   ASCII. В синтаксисе HTML имена тегов, даже те, что используются для
>   чужих элементов, могут быть записаны любым сочетанием букв нижнего и
>   верхнего регистра, которые при преобразовании во все строчные буквы
>   соответствуют имени тега элемента; Имена тегов не чувствительны к
>   регистру.

Но как вы можете помнить я приводил примеры которые не только содержат **ASCII alphanumerics**, как это понимать?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Спеки говорят следующее:

- Первым символом имени тега [должна быть буква ASCII](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#tag-open-state), иначе ошибка. [Поведение при ошибке тоже описывается.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parse-error-invalid-first-character-of-tag-name) Потому тег `<машина>` у вас превращается в тыкву.
- Следующими символами имени тега могут быть любые, [кроме перечисленных](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#tag-name-state) включая пробельные символы, слеш `/`, восклицательный знак и `>`. Натурально, на все последующие символы не накладывается никаких других каких-то особых ограничений. Потому вы видите что тег `<car-моя>` обрабатывается без ошибок.

Дальше [в определении HTML элемента](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-tag-name) мы читаем что он может состоять только из букв и цифр ASCII. И в том же абзаце читаем что есть ещё и [другие элементы](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#foreign-elements), которые, как можно понять из текста, подчиняются каким-то своим правилам. Цитата:

> In the HTML syntax, tag names, even those for *foreign elements*, may be written with any mix of lower- and uppercase letters that, when converted to all-lowercase, matches the element's tag name; tag names are case-insensitive.

Обратите внимание на использования *may*, что значит могут, а не *shall*, должны. Один из видов *других* элементов - это custom elements. Для них можно найти более [конкретное описание ограничений на используемые символы](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#valid-custom-element-name):

```
 "-" | "." | [0-9] | "_" | [a-z] | #xB7 | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] 
| [#xF8-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x203F-#x2040] 
| [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] 
| [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
```

Кириллица располагается в диапазоне U+0400–U+04FF, который, как легко видеть, входит в разрешенные.

**Потому, да: вы можете использовать кириллицу в названиях тегов везде кроме случая первого символа.** Первый символ имени тега должен быть из диапазона `[a-z]`, строго.

Чтобы вообще не было никаких сомнений, [документация приводит пример](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-core-concepts:dom-document-createelementns):

> Apart from these restrictions, a large variety of names is allowed, to give maximum flexibility for use cases like `<math-α>` or `<emotion->`.

В этой цитате явно и однозначно говорится что вы можете использовать теги вида `<math-α>` или `<emotion->`.

Comment: Все верно вы описываете токенизацию входных символов. Но кроме токенизации есть еще правила описанные в https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags и вот они не сходятся, почему так?

Comment: Если вы делаете нестандартный элемент, то правила по ссылке к нему не относятся.

Comment: Чем подкрепляется ваш аргумент (о нестандартном элементе речь)?

Comment: Текстом по вашей ссылке и описанием работы парсера, в котором явно и однозначно не требуется чтобы символы кроме первого были буквами из ASCII.

Comment: И который текст из моей ссылки говорит что: *"Если вы делаете нестандартный элемент, то правила по ссылке к нему не относятся"*?

Comment: @MaximPro дополнил ответ

Comment: Я все равно не понял куда конкретно вы ссылаетесь. Который текст черным по белому это явно говорит?

Comment: Смотрите ссылку на определение элемента

Comment: Ну и где там речь о каких-либо других элементах?

Comment: знаете вообще даже css реагирует также первая буква класса или id должна быть не цифрой иначе все - ошибка, невалидно, атата так что я  думаю что @sanmai наиболее близок к истине.. кроме того правда и то что браузеры работающие на разных движках по разному интерпретируют теги и работают сними так что тут скорее речь не о спецификации а об интерпертации их браузерами и последующей работе с  тегами

Comment: @BroouzerKing речь о спецификации и конкретных вещах. Кроме того я спрашиваю как раз по стандарту который сейчас активен, а он активен для большинства браузеров, в этой спецификации есть пометки в каждой главе какие браузеры поддерживают функционал. И не надо придумывать что браузеры интерпретируют по своему. У браузера есть четкие инструкции и эти инструкции следовать стандарту!

Comment: @MaximPro добавил цитату

Comment: **Foreign elements** - Elements from the MathML namespace and the SVG namespace. То есть это никак не касается **custom elements**.

Comment: Там написано что это foreign elements могут быть написаны в таком же стиле, но в остальном документ не делает никаких assumptions касаемо обязательного отсутствия других букв в названиях тегов, кроме случая первой буквы.

Comment: Это хорошо что вы сказали про custom elements. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Ну я думаю так уже никаких сомнений не должно остаться. @MaximPro

Comment: Там где использовано `may`, речь идет о комбинации имени тега с помощью любого регистра, т.е речи о символах которые не имеют регистра речи не идет и к тому же это относится к foreign elements. Не знаю я все время переводил `shall` как *следует*, а `must` как *должен*.

Comment: Хорошо, значит эти правила (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags) используются для определенных стандартом тегов, но не применяется для custom elements?

Comment: В этих правилах (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags) нет ничего, что мешало бы использовать уникод дальше первого символа.

Comment: @MaximPro почему вы считаете что правила по ссылке - не сходятся?

Comment: Там же конкретно сказано что символы которые там используются это ASCII alphanumeric,и ни о каком юникоде речь не идет. Вот в чем проблема.

Comment: Хотите мы продолжим обсуждение в чате? Если что добавите в свой ответ, то чего мы наговорим.

Comment: В ответе всё сказано, даже цитата из документации приведена где написано черным по белому что в тегах можно использовать уникод, и даже приведены примеры с эмодзи. Ещё раз, **цитата из документации с тегами со смайликами**. Уж куда тут дальше объяснять!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80210/discussion-between-sanmai-and-maximpro).

Answer (score 8):

Боюсь то что вы ищите написано нигде: browsers are known to tolerate and try to interpret all kinds of broken markup.

Это работа движка браузера(советую попробовать ваши теги в разных движках: IE8/9/11 Edge Safari FireFox Chromium) и сравнить результаты.
[это удобно сделать тут](https://app.crossbrowsertesting.com/)

Недавно боролся с вопросом можно ли ставить `<meta>` вне `<head>` или `<body>` оказывается нельзя, но большинство движков браузеров поймут что я сделал ошибку и переместят `<meta>` в `<head>`

[Подробнее тут.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447842/what-happens-if-the-meta-tags-are-present-in-the-document-body)

Comment: Написаны в разделе https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#tokenization однако в этой ссылке описывается токенизация входного потока символов. Но мой вопрос звучит в смущении того что есть раздел https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags в котором тоже описывается (не токенизация) но тоже построение тега.